# php foreach as variable

Tags: php, foreach

I'd like to use foreach to loop though an array list and add an element to each array.

```
$tom = array('aa','bb','cc');
$sally = array('xx','yy','zz');

$myArrays = array('tom','sally');

 foreach($myArrays as $arrayName) {
     ${$arrayName}[] = 'newElement';
 }
```

Is the use of ${$arrayName}[] the best way to do this?  Is there another option rather than using curly braces?  It currently works but I'm just wondering if there is a better alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use references.

```
$myArrays = array(&$tom, &$sally);

foreach($myArrays as &$arr) {
  $arr[] = 'newElement';
}
```

Comment: References aren't needed.

foreach ($myArrays as $i => $arr) { $myArrays[$i][] = "foo"; }

Comment: it's still a reference stored in `$myArrays`, otherwise `$myArrays[$i]` will be copies of `$tom` and `$sally` instead of the originals. Technically, it will hold the originals until they are changed, at which point php will copy them.

Answer (score 5):

If you're stuck to that structure, I would say stick to what you're doing there. But a comment might be nice.

If you can rearrange things, why not nest them?

```
$tom = array('aa','bb','cc');
$sally = array('xx','yy','zz');

$myArrays = array(&$tom, &$sally); // store the actual arrays, not names

// note the & for reference, this lets you modify the original array inside the loop
foreach($myArrays as &$array) {
    $array[] = 'newElement';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No curly braces needed.

```
$$arrayName[]
```

The original line is maybe a bug in PHP?

Although I wonder why you would ever need to do this anyway...

Comment: Actually, for arrays, curly braces are needed. Test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Some people will scold you for using variable variables.  You could do something like this:

```
$tom = array('aa','bb','cc');
$sally = array('xx','yy','zz');

$myArrays = array(&$tom, &$sally);

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($myArrays); ++$i) {
    $myArrays[$i][] = 'newElement';
}
```

Comment: using a regular for loop instead of foreach seems needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried, but should work, too:

```
$tom = array('aa','bb','cc');
$sally = array('xx','yy','zz');

$myArrays = array('tom','sally');

foreach($myArrays as $key => $value) {
    $$value[] = 'newElement';
}
```